# overriding defconfig in bbappend file

Tags: yocto

In my chip vendors recipe they define

```
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"
```

In my own layer, I want to override their defconfig and use my own.
I have a bbappend file in my recipe-kernel layer that adds my own defconfig file. My bbappend file:

```
SECTION = "kernel"
SUMMARY = "Kernel config and device tree customization"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"
SRC_URI += "file://tree_changes.diff"
```

The tree_changes.diff file is being applied so my bbappend file is being used at least for that.

The problem is that the vendor defconfig is always used. I dont really want to touch the vendors recipes, is there any better way of overriding the defconfig?

The chip vendor (Atmel/Microchip) bbfile is here:
https://github.com/linux4sam/meta-atmel/blob/dunfell/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-at91_5.4.bb

Comment: To override a recipe, the `.bbappend` is the best way. If it does not work, there is something else. Can you provide us the chip vendor recipe (the original .bb)?

Comment: ok good to know at least im in the right direction. My bbappend file also applies a device tree diff which definately is being applied. I added the chip vendor and lnik to their bb file. I still want to use their bb file as they do other things...I just want to use my own defconfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that your defconfig file is not located under ${THISDIR}/files/<machine> in your layer but rather under ${THISDIR}/files ?

${THISDIR}/files/<distro> or ${THISDIR}/files/<machine> have a higher priority than just ${THISDIR}/files.

The different defconfig files are located in

- ${THISDIR}/files/at91sam9
- ${THISDIR}/files/sam9x60
- ${THISDIR}/files/sama5
- ${THISDIR}/files/sama5d4

in vendor meta-layer, so they would still be used.

So you would need to move your defconfig file to ${THISDIR}/files/<your_machine> in your custom layer. Note that FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend = "${THISDIR}/files:" remains the same in the recipe. Yocto takes care of extending the path.

Comment: To complete Markus answer, one would thus need to put the defconfig of the bbappend into `${THISDIR}/files/<family_or_machine_youre_building>`. Note that `FILESEXTRAPATHS` remains the same in the recipe, it'll take care of finding it in the subdirectory corresponding to the family or machine being built.

Comment: Thank you @qschulz - I updated the answer to make it more precise.

Comment: This is exactly the case. I am putting it in ${THISDIR}/files. Thank you.. I cant test this out yet but when I do i'll mark this as the answer. Any idea where it says abut putting it in ${THISDIR}/files/<machine> having a higher priority?

Comment: It's described here https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-FILESPATH